# How to make an overlaid column chart in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to make a bar/column chart that looks like so:
[image]
(credit to [Matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/overlay-bar-graphs.html) for the image)

In my case I'm representing a snap-shot of a solution state: I have some variables and each have an associated upper-bound constraint.

**Importantly** my variables can actually be above their upper-bound (implying the solution state isn't constraint-abiding), hence a `stacked` column chart isn't a good option.

The above style has each skinny bar overlaid on-top of its corresponding wider one, which seems like the perfect solution to communicate my data. Is there a way to do this with `LibreOffice Calc`?

The only options I see are styles: `normal`, `stacked`, `percent stacked` and (`3-D`) `deep`. Each of these are a terrible visual for my problem.

I'm okay with a complicated/hacky solution if necessary, so long as the image produced looks professional - and so long as I can edit my data easily and see its changes reflected in the chart (not having to re-do a bunch of work each time).

Comment: Libreoffice does not support this graph type. Your solution indeed will be hacky. It will not be easy to find a hacky solution that at the same time allows for quick update when the data change. Probably this could be achieved more easily (but then requiring to use some code) in R-cran.

Comment: @vanadium, thanks for your reply. I guess I can just use `matlab`, it's just a shame because I already have a bunch of graphs set up in `calc` and I'll have to move them across. Feel free to offer that as an answer and I'll accept it.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Libreoffice does not support this type of graph. It will not be easy to find a solution using LO, even hacky, that would at the same time allow for a quick update when the data change.

You will probably need to look for other tools. This could likely be achieved more easily - however requiring some coding - in tools such as R-cran, GNU Octave or GNUplot.

A quick attempt on how it could work in R-cran is:

```
temphigh=c(23,22,18)
templow=c(20,18,15)
barplot(temphigh)
barplot(templow,col="red",space=c(0.9,1.4,1.4),width=0.5,add=T)
```